# Rails 4 should I set the instance variables or chain on the methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dry

I am on Rails 4 and have a very simple question.

Say you have a `User` model which `has_one` `Account` and `Account` `belongs_to` the `User`

On the user show page, I would like to display user attributes as well as account attributes.

In the users_controller I could do it like this:

```
def show
  @user    = User.find(params[:id])
  @account = @user.account
end
```

and then in the view:

```
<%= @user.name %> 
<%= @account.id %>
```

**OR**

I could just set the user instance variable:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

and in the view:

```
<%= @user.name %>
<%= @user.account.id %>
```

Is there a difference in these? Is one of them the 'Rails Way'? I may be over thinking this, but am just curious as to what is correct here.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that it's really a matter of preference.  If I were the one writing it, I would assign it to a variable if it were going to be used multiple times across the view.  If it is only used once, it seems redundant to assign it.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended best practice is that you limit to one instance variable per controller action and @person.account.id (chaining) is not allowed.

See https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers

Using decorators is good idea (e.g. Draper). The above example too simple to add another gem. You can use delegate in rails

See http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Comment: Why is chaining not allowed? @Shishir

Comment: It is allowed, its not recommended. you can make exception once in a while. The problem which chaining is that you break encapsulation from OO perspective and also difficult to refactor.